# Java Maven Run Time Building Errors

Tags: maven, build, runtime-error

COMPILATION ERROR
 No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
Finished at: 2018-02-06T12:16:07+05:30
 Final Memory: 9M/63M
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project  Compilation failure
No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 For more information about the errors and possible solutions

Comment: Did you set the environment variable "JAVA_HOME" to the home directory of your JDK? This caused the same error for me a while ago. Otherwise just search on stackoverflow for solutions - there are quite a couple discussions on this topic but some of them depend on the operating system you use.

Comment: Kindly provide the Solution for this

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning check if the JAVA_HOME property is set:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

expected result, e.g.:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
```

Secondly, verify if you have javac on the path. To do so run the following command:

```
javac -version
```

expected result, e.g.:

```
javac 1.8.0_101
```

Comment: Do you mean `echo %JAVA_HOME%`?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got the same error in Java execution in Eclipse IDE, after adding the java 1.8 version by Right click on the Java Project, Click on Java Build Path -> Libraries and add Java 1.8 JDK installed in your system , This issue will be resolved .